# Ruby on Rails, Paperclip: "identify" command working in cmd but not in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I've installed ImageMagick on my Windows 7 64bit and I have the Paperclip Gem. My User model looks like this:

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Paperclip
  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {
      :thumb=> "100x100#",
      :small  => "150x150>" }
  end
```

In paperclip.rb and development.rb I have:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.6.7-Q16'
```

My _form looks like this:

```
    <%= form_for(@user, :html => { :multipart => true } )  do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :crypted_password %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :crypted_password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_salt %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :password_salt %>
  </div>
 <%= f.file_field :photo%>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>

enter code here
```

I'm getting the following error when uploading an image:

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: C:/Users/John/AppData/Local/Temp/stream20110212-6576-1us1cdl.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

I'm able to use identify in my cmd on that image and it returns metadata about the image without problems.

Please help if you can. I've been stuck on this one issue for over a day now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated the following in development.rb and it started working

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:/Progra~1/ImageM~1.8-q'
```

This was on a Windows 2008 32 Bit Server

Answer (score 7):

This is due to a bug in the Paperclip gem in `lib/paperclip/command_line.rb` [file](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/v2.3.10/lib/paperclip/command_line.rb#L42).

```
def full_path(binary)
  [self.class.path, binary].compact.join("/")
end
```

The `full_path` function generates command file name with a backslash.

```
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16"/identify
```

This command fails on Windows as the `cmd` shell throws an error when the command file is a [long file name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_filename) with a back slash.

There are two ways to fix the issue.

#### Use the [short file name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) as the command path.

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:/PROGRA~1/IMAGEM~1.0-Q'
```

*Note*: You can get the short file name as follows:

```
dir /x "C:\Program Files*"
dir /x "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16*"
```

#### Monkey patch the Paperclip gem in `config\initializers\paperclip.rb`.

I tested this on 2.3.11.

```
class Paperclip::CommandLine
  def full_path(binary)
    [self.class.path, binary].compact.join(File::ALT_SEPARATOR||File::SEPARATOR)
  end
end
```

Now, the `identify` command is generated with the correct path seperator.

```
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16"\identify
```

I prefer the second approach as `command_path` is easier to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt and type `echo %path%` your imagemagick path should appear there.

Also try changing the `:command_path` to `C:/Progra~1/ImageM~1`